# When shouldn't a method come from an interface in OOP? Or should it be everything except getters/setters?

Tags: oop, interface, composition

Maybe I'm taking the concept of composition too far but I don't understand why a class would ever declare its own methods, besides getters and setters for it's own fields.

Like if I have the class `cow`. Cows can moo and be milked. So I could define `moo()` and `milk()` in `cow`, but I could also have `cow` implement the `IMooer` and `IMilkable` interfaces. Especially with `IMilkable`, maybe I also have the `goat` and `yak` classes that'll inherit from it.

Then I could say well `cow`s are `animal`s, and all `animal`s should implement `IWalker` and `IEater` etc.

Is there anything a cow can do that shouldn't be in an interface? Even if there's something only cows can do: for example only cows can moo, why not put that in `IMooer` anyway? In fact, why not make `ISpeaker` or something and override a function into a moo.

Why should a class ever declare a method besides a getter or a setter, instead of implementing it  from an interface?

Comment: What language are you using? It matters because limitations inherent some languages (looking at you, Java) impose OOP design constraints that don't apply to other languages that are more flexible (e.g. multi-inheritance and structural typing in C++, TypeScript)

Comment: @Dai well the question arose when I was working in C++ (with multiple-inheritance) but I use C++, Java, and C# for school.